# Calculating Probability Of Value With Dice

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, dice

I am trying to write a program to calculate the probability of a number of dice thrown equaling a specif value. I have done some working out in excel, to try and find a patter, but I am at a loss. At first the values seem to follow the pattern of Pascal's triangle, but then they start get weird. I'd love some help (I am a hobby programmer, not a mathematician). The data for these patterns I have so far is this:

1D6

- 1    1
- 2    1
- 3    1
- 4    1
- 5    1
- 6    1

2D6

- 2    1
- 3    2
- 4    3
- 5    4
- 6    5
- 7    6
- 8    5
- 9    4
- 10   3
- 11   2
- 12   1

3D6

- 3    1
- 4    3
- 5    6
- 6    10
- 7    15
- 8    21
- 9    25
- 10   27
- 11   27
- 12   25
- 13   21
- 14   15
- 15   10
- 16   6
- 17   3
- 18   1

4D6

- 4    1
- 5    4
- 6    10
- 7    20
- 8    35
- 9    56
- 10   80
- 11   104
- 12   125
- 13   140
- 14   146
- 15   140
- 16   125
- 17   104
- 18   80
- 19   56
- 20   35
- 21   20
- 22   10
- 23   4
- 24   1

Comment: See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html

Comment: [OEIS A063260](https://oeis.org/A063260)